# Creating a graph from local minima of 2D array

Tags: python, graph-theory

I have a 2D array and want to create a spatial graph from the local minimum of the array (Nodes = minima; edges = the Euclidian distance between nodes). I also want to implement an edge cut procedure when the edges between the nodes cross a "mountain" in the original data.

Currently, i am using the below code to get the coordinates, and then was going to learn how to use the GeoPandas package to create graphs from the coordinates and figure out the edge cut thing. But I am wondering if there is a known solution or better package to work in? or a way to create the appropriate graph directly from the original data?

```
def local_minima(array2d):
    return ((array2d <= np.roll(array2d,  1, 0)) &
            (array2d <= np.roll(array2d, -1, 0)) &
            (array2d <= np.roll(array2d,  1, 1)) &
            (array2d <= np.roll(array2d, -1, 1)))

def find_cood_local_min(bool_array):
    coords = []
    for x in range(len(bool_array[:, 0])):
        for y in range(len(bool_array[0,:])):
            if bool_array[x,y] == True:
                coords.append([x,y])
                
    return coords
```

Comment: You can use NetworkX to create the graph and perform graph algorithms and use GeoPandas for plotting or exporting. You would have to implement a function to extract the path between two nodes as an array and then check if there is a local maxima there.
Alternatively you can use something like OpenCV to create the lines as a mask to then extract the values from the array2d.